# Mistake in glmer plot?

Tags: r, plot, lme4

I am trying to plot the output of a glmer model.

```
MOD1A <- glmer(y ~ Treenumb +  Pineprop +  Wood +  Pineprop*Wood +    
                   (1|Site) +  (1|obs), family=binomial,  data = PRET10)
```

where

- y = binary response
- Treenumb and Pineprop = continues variable
- Wood =
  factor (presence/abscence).

Here is the output summary table:

```
Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6608 -0.7533 -0.4580  0.9569  2.0366

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 obs    (Intercept) 6.388e-10 2.527e-05
 Site   (Intercept) 1.710e-01 4.135e-01
Number of obs: 100, groups:  obs, 100; Site, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -2.23318    0.98193  -2.274   0.0229 *
Treenum      0.04914    0.02147   2.289   0.0221 *
Pineprop     0.72572    0.94411   0.769   0.4421  
Wood         1.43132    0.73979   1.935   0.0530 .
Pineprop:   -2.05649    0.95801  -2.147   0.0318 *
Wood
```

I tried to plot the interaction between Pine:Wood using this code:

```
x<-seq(0,1,length=100)
fits.woodpres <- ((-2.23318+1.43132) + (0.72572-2.05649)*x)
fits.woodabsc <- ((-2.23318-1.43132) + (0.72572+2.05649)*x)
plot(PRET10$pineprop[PRET10$wood=="pres"],fitted(MOD1A)[PRET10$wood=="pres"], pch=20,las=1,ylab="Predation", xlab="Pine proportion",ylim = c(0,1))
lines(x,invlogit(fits.woodpres))
points(PRET10$pineprop[PRET10$Wood=="abs"],fitted(MOD1A)[PRET10$Wood=="abs"], col=2, pch=20)
lines(x,invlogit(fits.woodabs),col=2
```

SO, basically I tried to obtain estimate and the slope of the interaction directly from summary table (contrast poly).

Here is the plot:

[image]

As you can see the curves are quite low in relation to the points. Should be a problem of the code for plotting?

I always tried to look in the forum for my problems but this time I really didn't find any solution.

Comment: When the distribution is binomial the fitted values are log-odds relative to the Intercept, which it doesn't appear you are including in your calculations. These are known as 'treatment contrasts'.

Comment: Generally `predict` methods will yield more, ... there's no better word for it, .... predictable ... results, and using type= "response". I just checked to see if that was an option here and it appears to be see `?predict.merMod` in pkg:{lme4}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Predict is the best way. Unlikely I don t know much further than this:                                                                      `Newmod <- predict(MOD1A,re.form=NA,type="response")... I never used predict, I really do not know how to use it